# Matlab: poor accuracy of optimizers/solvers

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, solver, equation-solving, optimization

I am having difficulty achieving sufficient accuracy in a root-finding problem on Matlab.  I have a function, `Lik(k)`, and want to find the value of `k` where `Lik(k)=L0`. Basically, the problem is that various built-in Matlab solvers (`fzero`, `fminbnd`, `fmincon`) are not getting as close to the solution as I would like or expect.

`Lik()` is a user-defined function which involves extensive coding to compute a numerical inverse Laplace transform, etc., and I therefore do not include the full code.  However, I have used this function extensively and it appears to work properly.  `Lik()` actually takes several input parameters, but for the current step, all of these are fixed except `k`. So it is really a one-dimensional root-finding problem.

I want to find the value of `k >= 165.95` for which `Lik(k)-L0 = 0`. `Lik(165.95)` is less than `L0` and I expect `Lik(k)` to increase monotonically from here.  In fact, I can evaluate `Lik(k)-L0` in the range of interest and it appears to smoothly cross zero: e.g. `Lik(165.95)-L0 = -0.7465, ..., Lik(170.5)-L0 = -0.1594, Lik(171)-L0 = -0.0344, Lik(171.5)-L0 = 0.1015, ... Lik(173)-L0 = 0.5730, ..., Lik(200)-L0 = 19.80`. So it appears that the function is behaving nicely.

However, I have tried to "automatically" find the root with several different methods and the accuracy is not as good as I would expect...

Using `fzero(@(k) Lik(k)-L0)`: If constrained to the interval `(165.95,173)`, `fzero` returns `k=170.96` with `Lik(k)-L0=-0.045`.  Okay, although not great.  And for practical purposes, I would not know such a precise upper bound without a lot of manual trial and error.  If I use the interval `(165.95,200)`, `fzero` returns `k=167.19` where `Lik(k)-L0 = -0.65`, which is rather poor.  I have been running these tests with *Display* set to *iter* so I can see what's going on, and it appears that `fzero` hits `167.19` on the 4th iteration and then stays there on the 5th iteration, meaning that the change in `k` from one iteration to the next is less than `TolX` (set to 0.001) and thus the procedure ends.  The exit flag indicates that it successfully converged to a solution.

I also tried minimizing `abs(Lik(k)-L0)` using `fminbnd` (giving upper and lower bounds on `k`) and `fmincon` (giving a starting point for `k`) and ran into similar accuracy issues.  In particular, with `fmincon` one can set both `TolX` and `TolFun`, but playing around with these (down to 10^-6, much higher precision than I need) did not make any difference.  Confusingly, sometimes the optimizer even finds a k-value on an earlier iteration that is closer to making the objective function zero than the final k-value it returns.

So, it appears that the algorithm is iterating to a certain point, then failing to take any further step of sufficient size to find a better solution.  Does anyone know why the algorithm does not take another, larger step?  Is there anything I can adjust to change this? (I have looked at the list under *optimset* but did not come up with anything useful.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If solvers don't do the trick, it might be an indication that your function does not behave well around the points that you try to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have a 'wild' function that does appear to be monotone in the region, a fairly small range of interest, and not a very high requirement in precision I think all criteria are met for recommending the *brute force* approach.

Assuming it does not take too much time to evaluate the function in a point, please try this:

Find an upperbound `xmax` and a lower bound `xmin`, choose a preferred `stepsize` and evaluate your function at

```
xmin:stepsize:xmax
```

If required (and monotonicity really applies) you can get another upper and lower bound by doing this and repeat the process for better accuracy.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your reply! The function is rather slow to evaluate, but I think you are right that a brute force approach would make sense for this particular evaluation. In general, I would like to be able to do similar evaluations many times over (this line is actually inside a loop) and in a more automatized way so that the method generalizes without so much user trial-and-error. So I would still be happy to hear any further suggestions from anyone about a more "automatic" way to do this!

Comment: @HelenAlex Assuming monotonicity, you could just cut the range into n parts (say 5 or 10). Then find the lowest value and set the new range to be lowestValue+-oldrange/n. This can easily be done in a loop and should give you a fairly good approximation in just a few steps.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem while using fmincon. Here is how I fixed it.

I needed to find the solution of a function (single variable) within an optimization loop (multiple variables). Because of this, I needed to provide a large interval for the solution of the single variable function. The problem is that fmincon (or fzero) does not converge to a solution if the search interval is too large. To get past this, I solve the problem inside a while loop, with a huge starting upperbound (1e200) with the constraint made on the fval value resulting from the solver. If the resulting fval is not small enough, I decrease the upperbound by a factor. The code looks something like this:

```
fval = 1;
factor = 1;
while fval>1e-7
    UB = factor*1e200;
    [x,fval,exitflag] = fminbnd(@(x)function(x,...),LB,UB,options);
    factor = factor * 0.001;
end
```

The solver exits the while when a good solution is found. You can of course play also with the LB by introducing another factor and/or increase the factor step.
My 1st language isn't English so I apologize for any mistakes made.

Cheers,
Cristian

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple bisection method? You always evaluate the middle of a certain interval and then reduce this to the right or left part so that you always have one bound giving a negative and the other bound giving a positive value. You can reduce to arbitrary precision very quickly. Since you reduce the interval in half each time it should converge very quickly.

I would suspect however there is some other problem with that function in that it has discontinuities. It seems strange that fzero would work so badly. It's a deterministic function right?

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your answer.  Yes, I agree that a simple bisection method should work, and I might end up implementing this.  However, since fzero uses bisection among other methods, I originally expected it would do at least as well as anything I coded myself. I was also surprised that fzero worked so badly (yes, my function is deterministic). I tried evaluating at several points in the relevant range (see original post) and the function appeared continuous, but it's true there could be a problem at a point I didn't check. I guess any problem would also show up in the bisection method?

Comment: If fzero already uses bisection there's no point in reimplementing it. I see that it can return [error codes](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html).